# How to find the distribution of $Y = {e^{aX}}$ when $X$ is an exponential random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

How to find the distribution of $Y = {e^{aX}}$ when $X$ is an exponential random variable with ${f_X}\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{\lambda }\exp \left( { - \frac{x}{\lambda }} \right)$ and $a>0$ ?

First attemp with $a=1$ by using Mathematica return a **Pareto Distribution**
[image]
However, for $a=3$ or in general $a>0$, Mathematica cannot do anything:
[image]
Please help me with this !
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are uncomfortable with a manual change of variables on the density, then use the cumulative distribution functions

- $\mathbb P(X \le x) = 1-\exp \left( { - \frac{x}{\lambda }} \right)$ if $x \ge 0$, and $=0$ if $x \le 0$
- $\mathbb P(Y \le e^{ax}) = 1-\exp \left( { - \frac{x}{\lambda }} \right)$ if $x \ge 0$, and $=0$ if $x \lt 0$
- $\mathbb P(Y \le y) = 1-\exp \left( { - \frac{\frac1a \log_e(y)}{\lambda }} \right) =1-y^{-\frac{1}{a\lambda}}$ if $y \ge 1$, and $=0$ if $y \lt 1$
- $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{a\lambda}y^{-\frac{1}{a\lambda}-1}$ if $y \ge 1$, and $=0$ if $y \lt 1$

which is indeed a Pareto distribution with minimum $1$

Comment: Thank you so much !
on this line $\mathbb P(Y \le y) = 1-\exp \left( { - \frac{\frac1a \log_e(y)}{\lambda }} \right) =1-y^{-\frac{1}{a\lambda}}$ does the condition  $y \geqslant 1$ appear because ${e^{aX}} \geqslant 1$ for non-negative $x$ ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh  My thinking was $e^{a0}=e^0=1$ since $a>0$ makes $e^{ax}$ an increasing function

Comment: In the case $Y = {e^{aX}} + N$ where $N$ is some real positive number, does that mean that $y \geqslant 1 + N$ ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh Yes if $X\ge 0$ and $a>0$

Answer (score 2):

Because $X$ is exponential, we know $P(X \geq 0) = 1$, which means $P(Y \geq 1) = 1$, so the PDF of $Y$ will be zero outside $[1, \infty)$.

We know that the CDF of $X$ is
$$
P(X \leq z) = \int_{0}^z \lambda^{-1} e^{-\lambda^{-1} x} \, dx = 1 - e^{-\lambda^{-1} z}
$$

Then write down the CDF of $Y$ and use what you know: for $y \geq 1$,
\begin{align*}
P(Y \leq y) &= P( e^{a X} \leq y ) \\
            &= P( a X \leq \log y ) \\
            &= P( X \leq a^{-1} \log y ) \\
            &= 1 - e^{-(a \lambda)^{-1} \log y} \\
            &= 1 - e^{\log y^{-(a \lambda)^{-1}}} \\
            &= 1 - y^{-(a \lambda)^{-1}}
\end{align*}

Let $\beta = (a \lambda)^{-1}$. Now differentiate with respect to $y$ on both sides to obtain, for $y \geq 1$,
$$
f_Y(y) = \beta y^{-\beta - 1}
$$
If you want, you can write out the PDF in full:
$$
f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 0 & y < 1 \\ \frac{\beta}{y^{\beta + 1}} & y \geq 1. \end{cases}
$$
This is the PDF of a Pareto random variable with parameter $\beta$ with $\beta = (a \lambda)^{-1}$ as above.  In Mathematica's notation, it would be ParetoDistribution[1,$\beta$].

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if you want to directly derive $f_Y(y)$, consider that

$$y=e^{ax}$$

$$x=\frac{1}{a}\log y$$

$$|x'|=\frac{1}{ay}$$

thus

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{ay\lambda}\left[e^{\log(1/y)}\right]^{1/(a\lambda)}=\frac{1}{a\lambda y^{1/(a\lambda)+1}}$$

This is your density setting $a=3$ and $\lambda=1$

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have +1 for your answer as well, may I ask what kind of mathematical software you are using ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh :https://www.integral-calculator.com/